# $\mathbb{F}_4(x,y) / \mathbb{F}_4(x)$ is a Galois extension, with $\mathbb{F}_4(x,y)$ a function field of an algebraic curve

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, galois-theory, finite-fields, algebraic-curves

> Consider the field extension $\mathbb{F}_4(x,y)/\mathbb{F}_4(x)$ where $y$ is a root of the polynomial
>   $$
> f(T)= x^4 + x^2T^2 + x^2T + x^2 + xT^2 + xT + T^4 + T^2 + 1 \in \mathbb{F}_4(x)[T].
> $$
>   I want to show that $\mathbb{F}_4(x,y)/\mathbb{F}_4(x)$ is a Galois extension.

I already proved that $f(T)$ is separable. Now, I was thinking to find the splitting field of $f(T)$ and note that it is $\mathbb{F}_4(x,y)$. Is that the best way to solve this? How can I find the splitting field of $f(T)$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not write simply $$f(T)= T^4 +\left(x^2+x+1\right)T^2+\left(x^2+x\right)T+1$$

Comment: Aha...wise. Well, add that $\;x^4\;$ there...or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that $f(T+1) = f(T+x) = f(T+x+1) = f(T)$.

This gives you explicitly the Galois group and proves that the extension is Galois.

Comment: very well! How do you think to do this?

Comment: I looked at a few specialisations for $x$ to see what the roots were and try to notice any obvious relation (I looked at each possible value of $x \in \Bbb F_4$) then I wondered, "what if $y \mapsto y +1$ actually worked ??". Then because of the symmetry of the coefficients of the polynomials, I realised it meant that $y \mapsto y+x$ and $y \mapsto y+x+1$ also worked. Also, if the galois group elements were more complicated, it would be an absolute pain to find them and check that they worked. Honestly I have no idea how to determine the Galois group of a random polynomial over such a field.